# Why are old questions suddenly showing up in DIY? Many are 1-5 years old

Tags: bug, late-answers

Recently I've seen questions that are quite old (1-5 years) suddenly appear on DIY recent questions. I don't seem to be able to close them as "late answers" , maybe I don't yet have enough reputation points to do that, but that's not the issue. The issue why did this suddenly start happening

Comment: Yes, thanks for the super rapid response.  I'm still a relative newbie here....just here over the last year.   I had no idea how complex the algorithms are.   Thanks for the link!

Comment: glad to see you don’t take the closing of your question negatively.

Comment: @EkadhSingh  I'm no snowflake, for sure, so no issues with closing it.   I've voted a few times to close questions is the DIY  part of SE bc they were off topic for the forum, so I get it.   Thanks again.

Comment: What was the particular reason?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'm using a shared PC and there was a bunch of junk history, cookies, links I didn't want, etc. etc.   So I did a mass delete of all that stuff.  Then the renewed link to SE took me to the DIY meta page.  I'll see if I can go directly to "newest questions" on the DIY page.   Thanks for your comments.